# How to run remote script on multiple host simultaneously

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a great amount of Linux servers to maintain. Frequently I need to run a script (*script.sh*) on all of them to get the health status, this script usually takes about 30-40 seconds to give an output. To facilitate maintenance tasks, I'm writing a shell script that uses SSH to loop through all remote hosts, run script.sh, collect output and write it to a log file in my local host. For the sake of this question, I have named this script *MyScript.sh*

The script works fine, however, it has to wait for the SSH output to continue to the next host. Because I have too many servers, and the commands runs in sequence, it take several minutes to finish. I would like to loop through all servers in parallel, without needing to wait for a response from each host.

Is there a way I can remotely run script.sh simultaneously on all host using MyScript.sh? Maybe run the ssh command in the background and somehow collect the output?

The output of script.sh is a single line separated by pipes. Such as the following

```
host1|49 days|10%|3.77%|27677/63997 MB|43% - /usr|38% - /usr|Optimal|No|40%|No
```

The output of Myscript.sh is the concatenation of the output from all host without pipes.

```
    Date       Hostname   Uptime     CPU     I/O      Free MEM           File System               INODES                   STATUS WWW       YYY             ZZZ                   XXX
    ===================================================================================================================================================================================================
    01/31/20   host1      44 days    5%      10.33%   38083/64000 MB     57% - /                   37% - /usr                OPTIMAL         No              40%                    No
    01/31/20   host2      45 days    11%     1.79%    27915/63997 MB     43% - /usr                38% - /usr                OPTIMAL         UP              7%                     OK
    01/31/20   host3      45 days    2%      1.89%    32145/63997 MB     43% - /usr                38% - /usr                OPTIMAL         UP              NO                     OK
    01/31/20   host4      45 days    11%     3.72%    52477/128637 MB    49% - /var                38% - /usr                OPTIMAL         UP              8%                     OK
    01/31/20   host5      45 days    6%      3.21%    65264/128637 MB    46% - /var                38% - /usr                OPTIMAL         UP              NO                     OK
    01/31/20   host6      45 days    7%      5.79%    56369/63997 MB     43% - /usr                38% - /usr                OPTIMAL         UP              NO                     No
    01/31/20   host7      45 days    6%      1.66%    56391/63997 MB     43% - /var                38% - /usr                OPTIMAL         UP              NO                     No
```

The core of MyScript.sh is the following:

```
(
    for ip in $IP_LIST;
    do
            echo "Checking $ip"

            ssh  -q -t $user@$ip 'sudo /tmp/script.sh' > /tmp/$$
            current_date=$(date +%D)
            printf "%-10s " "$current_date" >> $logfile

            while read line;
            do
                    echo $line | awk -F '|' '{printf("%-10s %-10s %-7s %-8s %-18s %-25s %-25s %-15s %-15s %-25s %-10s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11); }' >> $logfile

            done< /tmp/$$

    done
    )
```

In summary, I would like to optimize this script to run the above code simultaneously on multiple servers.
Thanks!

Comment: Very easy with **GNU Parallel**, see https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Remote-execution

Comment: Note that **GNU Parallel** is not a library, it is a single file containing Perl script, and Perl is included by default with most Linux distros and macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be to deploy a monitoring software with custom checks.

For the parrallel `ssh` problem, without install any binaries you could use this script I wrote a while ago.
Put in a file `mssh`, run `chmod u+x mssh` and then :

```
./mssh -s SERVER1 -s SERVER2 -C script.sh
```

The `mssh` file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly prog_name="$(basename "$0")"
readonly date="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"

# print help
usage() {
cat <<- EOF
usage: $prog_name options

parallel ssh executions.

OPTIONS:
   -c --cmd CMD              execute command CMD
   -s --host SRV             execute cmd on server SRV
   -C --cmd CMD_FILE         execute command contained in CMD_FILE
   -S --hosts-file SRV_FILE  execute cmd on all servers contained in SRV_FILE
   -h --help                 show this help

Examples:
   Run CMD on SERVER1 and SERVER2:
   ./$prog_name -s SERVER1 -s SERVER2 -c "CMD"

EOF
}

# test if an element is in an array
is_element(){
    local search=$1; shift;
    for e in "$@"; do [[ "$e" == "$search" ]] && return 0; done
    return 1
}

# parse arguments
for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        --help)           args+=( -h );;
        --host)           args+=( -s );;
        --hosts-file)     args+=( -S );;
        --cmd)            args+=( -c );;
        --cmd-file)       args+=( -C );;
        *)                args+=("$arg");;
    esac
done
set -- "${args[@]}"
while getopts "hs:S:c:C:" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
        h)  usage; exit 0;;
        s)  servers_array+=("$OPTARG");;
        S)  while read -r L; do servers_array+=("$L"); done < <( grep -vE "^ *(#|$)" "$OPTARG");;
        c)  cmd="$OPTARG";;
        C)  cmd="$(< "$OPTARG")"; file=$OPTARG;;
        *)  :;;
    esac
done
if [[ -z ${servers_array[0]} ]] || [[ -z $cmd ]]; then
    usage; exit 1
fi

# clean up created files at exit
trap "rm -f /tmp/pssh*$date" EXIT

[[ -n $file ]] && echo "executing command file : $file"  || echo "executing command : $cmd"
# run cmd on each server
for i in "${!servers_array[@]}"; do
    # executing cmd in subshell
    ssh -n "${servers_array[$i]}" "$cmd" > "/tmp/pssh_${i}_${servers_array[$i]}_${date}" 2>&1 &
    pid=$!
    pids_array+=("$pid")
    echo "${servers_array[$i]} - $pid"
done

# for each pid, set state to running
ps_state_array=( $(for i in "${!servers_array[@]}"; do echo "running"; done) )

echo "waiting for results..."
echo

# begin finished verifications
continue=true; attempt=0
while $continue; do

    # foreach ps
    for i in "${!pids_array[@]}"; do

        # if already finished skip
        [[ ${ps_state_array[$i]} == "finished" ]] && continue

        # else check if finished
        ps -o pid "${pids_array[$i]}" > /dev/null 2>&1  && ps_finished=false || ps_finished=true
        if $ps_finished; then
            ps_state_array[$i]="finished"
            echo -e "[ ${servers_array[$i]} @ $(date +%H:%M:%S) ]" | grep '.*' --color=always
            cat "/tmp/pssh_${i}_${servers_array[$i]}_${date}"
            rm -f "/tmp/pssh_${i}_${servers_array[$i]}_${date}"
            echo
        fi
    done    

    is_element "running" "${ps_state_array[@]}" || continue=false
    if $continue; then
        (( attempt < 5 )) && attempt=$(( attempt + 1 ))
        sleep $attempt
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks, I correct many of the alerts and more (function is not posix, /usr/bin/env bash better, ...). As mentionned I wrote the script a while ago.

Comment: @BDR, thanks for sharing you code. I reused it and adapted it to my needs, it really solves my question.. Also, I like that it works without installing any binaries

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks something like this:

```
doit() {
    ip="$1"
    echo "Checking $ip" >&2
    current_date=$(date +%D)
    printf "%-10s " "$current_date"

    ssh  -q -t $user@$ip 'sudo /tmp/script.sh' |
      awk -F '|' '{printf("%-10s %-10s %-7s %-8s %-18s %-25s %-25s %-15s %-15s %-25s %-10s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11); }' 
}
export -f doit
export user
parallel -j0 doit ::: $IP_LIST >> $logfile
```